# How to add Google Analitycs event by clicking link

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, attributes

I'd like to automate my work and add script which after clicking specific link (`<a>`) that contains `href="mailto"` or `href="tel:"` will automatically add gtag event. I've tried some solutions and I think the best way is to use setAttribute as in the example below

```
    const aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
      for(let i = 0; i<aTags.length; i++){
        const addAttribute = () => {
          if (aTags[i].getAttribute('href').includes('mailto')) {
              aTags[i].setAttribute("gtag", "('event', 'email')");      
          } else if (aTags[i].getAttribute('href').includes('tel:')) {  
              aTags[i].setAttribute("gtag", "('event', 'telefon');");  
          } 
        } 
        aTags[i].addEventListener('click', addAttribute)
    }
```

Unfortunately the result is `gtag="('event', 'email')"` but it should be `gtag('event', 'email')`. How could I remove the equals and quotation marks? Or is there any better way to do it?